# Sort object array dates, where dates are of string data type c#

Tags: c#, sorting, date, datetime

Trying to sort these datesw

```
object[] Dates = pivotGridFieldDates.GetUniqueValues();
```

result of Dates

```
9/10/2015
9/11/2015
9/2/2015
9/20/2015
9/25/2015
9/7/2015
9/8/2015
```

Dates format change as per the culture preference and I would like to sort these object array dates....

```
where Datetype of "Dates"  is {Name = "String" FullName = "System.String"}
```

---

My code

```
object[] Dates = pivotGridFieldDates.GetUniqueValues();
string result;

List<string> list=new List<string>();
var map = new List<String>();
foreach (var value in Dates)
{
    string map1= Convert.ToString(value);
    DateTime newdate = DateTime.ParseExact(map1, culture.ShortDatePattern,
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    result = newdate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    map.Add(result);
}
map.Sort();
```

---

After sorting,  how can I convert this "map" list  to object[] weeks dates again ?? and display dates in same date-format as it was before sorting...

Answer (score 4):

Rather than converting, sorting, and converting back, you could sort without conversion using a [custom comparison delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z(v=vs.110).aspx), like this:

```
Dates.Sort((lhs, rhs) => {
    var lhsDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Convert.ToString(lhs), culture.ShortDatePattern, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var rhsDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Convert.ToString(rhs), culture.ShortDatePattern, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    return lhsDate.CompareTo(rhsDate);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `OrderBy` (or maybe `OrderByDescending`) to sort sequence. Also no need to separate list - just `Select` to perform conversion like:

```
var listOfSortedStringDates = Dates.Select(v => DateTime.ParseExact( // parse
       v.ToString(),  // ToString as we have objects
       culture.ShortDatePattern, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
   .OrderBy(x=>x) // sort
   .Select(newdate => newdate.ToString(culture.ShortDatePattern)) // back to string
   .ToList();
```

As Matt Johnson pointed out you really just need to parse in `OrderBy` - no need to convert back and forth:

```
var listOfSortedStringDates = Dates
   .OrderBy(v => DateTime.ParseExact(
          v.ToString(), culture.ShortDatePattern, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
   .ToList();
```

Comment: Why not just do the parse in the OrderBy?  Then you don't have to convert twice.

Comment: @MattJohnson good point - separate steps are nicer to explain, but really more work. Also OrderBy caches all keys - so there is no extra calls to Parse anyway